How to use Line Printer with flutter windows app
Im trying to create flutter app to print salary slip of the employees in my organization. I am able to print PDF with my app but i have doubt that the same will work with line printer (Printronix P8000) intalled, as there website say that Printronix P8000 Plus supports the PDF. If thers any way around let me know.

I have checked the firmware version, but I believe it is not PLUS and currently, the printer is working on Windows XP.

I don't know this type of printer, but I imagine that there are printer drivers under Windows.
If this is the case, you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/printing
implementation is quite simple. I have use it with success for printing on POS printer in an Android application.

I am already using the printing package with the PDF package as per the documentation. However, it is doubtful that it will work with non-PLUS firmware as there's no documentation that it will support PDF.
